# Oracle Refresh Group Access

Tags: sql, oracle

I created refresh group and added materialized views to that group in schema A. I want to refresh from User B. But when I try to view the ALL_REFRESH and ALL_REFRESH_CHILDREN tables in schema B, no data is found. Should some kind of permission be given to user B to see these information ?

Answer (score 1):

Just "grant alter any materialized view to B" and you will be able to see these information and refresh the refresh group.

Answer (score 0):

you can give select privilege to schema B.

or an another option is to grant select on dba views to schema_b_user so that he can view all the MVs in the db

as sys or system user:-
grant select_catalog_role to schema_b_user;

and then select on dba_refresh and dba_refresh_children